# Resizing UIPopoverController

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uipopovercontroller

I have a UIPopoverController. I put a UINavigationController with two UITableViewcontrollers in it.

I create a subclassed UITableView, I'm able to set the size of the popover with `tableView.contentSizeForViewInPopover`:

```
if (self.myPopoverController.isPopoverVisible)
{
    [self.myPopoverController dismissPopoverAnimated:YES];
}
else
{
    MyRootTableView *rootTableView = [[MyRootTableView alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewStyleGrouped];
    MyRootTableView.contentSizeForViewInPopover = CGSizeMake(POPOVER_SIZE.width, [self createContentHeighForTableViewController:tableView]);
    MyRootTableView.boundaryDelegate = self;

    UINavigationController *navController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:tableViewController];
    navController.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleCoverVertical;
    navController.navigationBar.barStyle = UIBarStyleBlack;

    self.myPopoverController = [[UIPopoverController alloc] initWithContentViewController:navController];
    self.myPopoverController.delegate = self;

    [self.myPopoverController presentPopoverFromRect:frame inView:view permittedArrowDirections:arrowDirection animated:YES];
}
```

In the rootTableViewController's didSelectRowAtIndexPath:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    DetailedTableViewController *tableViewController = [[DetailedTableViewController alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewStyleGrouped];
    tableViewController.contentSizeForViewInPopover = CGSizeMake(POPOVER_SIZE.width, [self createContentHeighForTableViewController:tableViewController]);
    tableViewController.delegate = self.boundaryDelegate;

    [self.navigationController pushViewController:tableViewController animated:TRUE];
}
```

`createContentHeightForTableViewController:` calculates the height needed to show all the cells in the table view

So for the root tableViewController, I set the content size. When I create the detailed view controller, I set the `contentSizeForViewInPopover` to a different size. This works great. The issue I'm having is when I navigate back to the root table view, the `contentSizeForViewInPopover` is still set for the detail table view.

How can I resize the pop over when the table view is displayed or appears?

Answer (score 4):

Try to use `preferredContentSize` instead of `contentSizeForViewInPopover` on your `tableViewController` (`contentSizeForViewInPopover` is deprecated on iOS7)

Answer (score 0):

You should set `popoverContentSize` on the UIPopoverController directly in the viewWillAppear method of your parent view controller (or some other appropriate place).  Wherever you want to force the popover's content size to update.

Comment: So in the table view, set the content size in view will appear? How do I get to that property?

Comment: in tableViewController, it does have a property `setContentSizeForViewInPopover:`. It does not resize the UIPopoverController though.

Comment: Something's a little fishy about the code you posted.  I don't think UITableViewController has a "boundaryDelegate" property, but maybe you've got your own subclass of UITableViewController with an upward reference to the thing that owns myPopoverController.  That's great---in your UITableViewController subclass override viewWillAppear and call `self.whateverOwnsMyPopoverController.myPopoverController setPopoverContentSize:<whatever you like> animated:<try YES and NO, not sure which will look best>];`

Comment: Yes, I subclassed UITableViewController and added that delegate. But what I'm trying to do shouldn't have anything to do with my subclass so I tried to simplify by removing all the custom code. I don't quiet follow you though: So my mainViewController has `self.myPopoverController`. In mainVC, I create the UITableviewController and UINavigationController, put them into the UIPopoverController and present the popover. I don't know how to get back up to the mainViewController to reset its myPopoverController contentsize.

Comment: It looks like MyRootTableView has a reference to mainViewController via self.boundaryDelegate.  In MyRootTableView's implementation of viewWillAppear you could use `self.boundaryDelegate.myPopoverController setPopoverContentSize:animated:`.  If boundaryDelegate is declared as id<MyRootTableViewBoundaryDelegate> you may want to add a new method to the MyRootTableViewBoundaryDelegate protocol.  You could have a method in the protocol like "popoverController" returning self.myPopoverController.

Comment: Ok, I see where you are trying to go. Yes the delegate is declared as `id<MyRootTableViewBoundaryDelegate>`. I'll try adding a new protocol to call back and set the new `contentSizeForViewInPopover`

Comment: Ok, I moved it from `viewWillAppear` to `viewDidApear` and I can set `self.contentSizeForViewInPopover` (both this and the delegate call back works). It works when its first shown, but when I navigate back to the root tableView from the detail tableView, it doesn't work.